# Array retrieving issue in first index - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting data set for `$all_students` and try to insert some data into an array called `$student_array`.

```
//data collection
$all_students= Student::with('Customer')->where('std', $name)->get();

//create a new array
$student_array[] = array();

//loop and set array indexes
foreach ($all_studentsas $student)
        {
            $student_array[] = array(
                'description' => $student['description'],
                'cost'       => $student['cost']
            );
        }
```

when I `dd($student_array);` results looks like follows:

```
array:6 [
  0 => []
  1 => array:2 [
    "description" => "test Des sap two"
    "cost" => 10.0
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "description" => "test Des sap two"
    "cost" => 500.0
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "description" => "test Des sap two"
    "cost" => 50050.0
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    "description" => "test Des sap two"
    "cost" => 50000.0
  ]
  5 => array:2 [
    "description" => "test Des sap two"
    "cost" => 50000.0
  ]
]
```

what I don't understand is the first index. (**`0 => []`**)

Can anyone tell me why this appears and what I need is the array results to be as:

```
array:6 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "description" => "test Des sap two"
        "cost" => 10.0
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "description" => "test Des sap two"
        "cost" => 500.0
      ]
      2 => array:2 [
        "description" => "test Des sap two"
        "cost" => 50050.0
      ]
      3 => array:2 [
        "description" => "test Des sap two"
        "cost" => 50000.0
      ]
      4 => array:2 [
        "description" => "test Des sap two"
        "cost" => 50000.0
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: Would it be easier if you just selected the description and cost columns in `$all_students` as it would save the extra step just to extract the two fields.

Comment: thanks @NigelRen. I only use those 2 to ask this question brother. But I'm using about 15 data in that collection of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use next code:

```
//data collection
$maintenance_spare_parts = MaintenanceSparePart::with('maintenance.equipment.technicalCustomer')->where('spare_part', $name)->get();

//create a new array
$student_array = [];

//loop and set array indexes
foreach ($maintenance_spare_parts as $student)
        {
            $student_array[] = array(
                'description' => $student['description'],
                'cost'       => $student['cost']
            );
        }
```

That because you're pasing an empty array into `[0]` index of `$student_array`

by `$student_array[] = array();`

The right way to declare variable as array is `$student_array = [];` or `$student_array = array();`

Comment: Oh.. I dnt know how I missed it. Thanks a lot brother. Appreciate your help. Billion thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about just removing

```
$student_array[] = array();
```

`[]` from initilization, it makes `array[0]` by doing this.